# ControlSelect not firing in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, dom-events

The **OnControlSelect** DOM event is not firing in **IE11**.

Apparently this event is still valid in **IE11** and my research has not turned-up known issues with this event and **IE11**.

My application allows users to edit and format their pages. I use the **OnControlSelect** event to do some application housekeeping whenever the user selects a control.

Has anyone experienced this, and is there a solution, workaround or alternative approach? I have tried using just the **OnClick** event, but for the desired behavior to occur, this requires the user double-click instead of single-click the control (this change is not acceptable to the user-base).

The following example HTML works in **IE7** through **10**, but not in **IE11**.

Clicking on the border of a either of the boxes (DIVs) should cause **OnControlSelect** to fire, posting a dialog box.

```
<html>
  <body contenteditable="true">
    <div oncontrolselect="alert(1)" style="position:absolute; top:000; left:100; border: 12px solid red;   height:200; width:300;">Thing One</div>
    <p>
    <div oncontrolselect="alert(2)" style="position:absolute; top:100; left:200; border: 12px solid green; height:200; width:300;">Thing Two</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further research has yielded no insights to this problem. Updating my test system with latest patches has not corrected the issue either. Nor is **EnterpriseMode** a viable solution.

*MSDN* lists **Scribable Editing** as a *Legacy API* but is it *unclear* if this event is deprecated. Instead the entire API is documented to be valid for IE 5.5 upwards. Parts of the API clearly work, but neither the **ControlSelect** nor the **SelectionChange** event work on any of my systems with IE11.

As a work-around, I have added conditional code to my (C#) application, to hook the **Mousedown** event instead of **ControlSelect** when the user has selected IE11 as the application's internal browser. *I then adjusted my event handler to filter its invocations in order to mimic the conditions present when the* **ControlSelect** *event should fire.*

I do not view this as a general purpose solution, but it has gotten me out of a difficult bind.